# PowerBI: multiple entires for same identifier, count if any entry has a column value

Tags: duplicates, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that contains purchase numbers and associated comments. There may be multiple entries for each purchase number. I would like a count of how many unique purchase numbers do not have a comment.

So in the example below I would like to return a count of one as no entry for 300 has a comment.

| Purchase number | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Sale |
| 100 |  |
| 200 | Sale |
| 200 | Sale |
| 200 | Sale |
| 300 |  |
| 300 |  |

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a way to do this by:

- Creating a conditional column named "comment attached" which scored a 1 if the row had an entry in the comment column or a 0 if there was no comment
- Creating a second table which was grouped by purchase number and added a column into the second table with the operation Max of the comment attached column
- Made a measure to sum this column

Probably not the most efficient method but it works, would love suggestions on how to do this in a better way